# Storing Values into cassandra using python

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am storing the json i get from a file into cassandra. But i would like to increment the id everytime i get new data and now it is overwriting the existing data. I expect result to be as shown below.

```
PacketID    PacketValue

1              Json
2              Json
3              Json
```

Here is my code.

```
import json
doc= (json.dumps(sw.get(),indent=4))
KEYSPACE = "mykeyspace"

def createKeySpace():
    cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['172.17.0.2'])
    session = cluster.connect()
    session.execute(""" CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS %s WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2' } """ % KEYSPACE)
    session.set_keyspace(KEYSPACE)
    session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wireless (PacketID int , PacketValue text, PRIMARY KEY(PacketID) );")

def insert_wireless():
    cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['172.17.0.2'])
    session = cluster.connect()
    PacketID=0
    PacketID=PacketID+1
    session.execute("""INSERT INTO mykeyspace.wireless(PacketID, PacketValue)
    VALUES(%s,%s)""",
    (PacketID,doc))


if __name__=="__main__":
    #start_node()
    th1=threading.Thread(target=createKeySpace())
    th1.start()
    threads=threading.Thread(target=insert_wireless())
    threads.start()
    threads.join()
```

Comment: use `uuid` or `timeuuid` as `packetId` column type.. if not feasible then use some counter table or external file or any other in-memory database to maintain the last inserted Id value and then read that value increment it and write to cassandra.. if written successfully increase counter

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using Uuid.uuid(1)